# News.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Tags: reactjs, react-state, async.js

I am getting error of** "News.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')"** when ever i am clicking on next button.
error occur in URL of handle next click button event.
its a news app in the next button i want to display page 2 of news
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV7lG.png) code of news component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Newsitem from "./Newsitem";

export class News extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  /* this.handleNextClick = this.handleNextClick.bind(this)
  this.handlePreviousClick = this.handlePreviousClick.bind(this) */
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      loading: false,
      page:1
    };
  }
 async componentDidMount(){
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey&page=${this.page.state+1}&pagesize=${this.props.pagesize}`;
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    console.log(parsedData);
    this.setState({articles: parsedData.articles,
                    totalresults:parsedData.totalresults });
  }
  handleNextClick =  async ()=>{
    console.log("next")
    if(!this.page.state + 1 > Math.ceil(this.state.totalresults/this.props.pagesize)){
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey&page=${this.page.state+1}&pagesize=${this.props.pagesize}`;
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    console.log(parsedData);
    this.setState({page : this.state.page + 1 ,
      articles : parsedData.articles });
    }
  }
  handlePreviousClick = async()=>{
    console.log("Previous")
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey&page=${this.page.state+1}&pagesize=${this.props.pagesize}`;
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json()
    console.log(parsedData);
    this.setState({page: this.state.page - 1,
                articles: parsedData.articles})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container my-4 ">
        <h1 className="text-center">NewsMonkey - TOP Headlines</h1>
        
        <div className="row">
          {this.state.articles.map((element)=>{
            return <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
            <Newsitem  title = {element.title?element.title.slice(0,40):""} description={element.description?element.description.slice(0,80):""} imgUrl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl = {element.url}/>
          </div>
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="container d-flex justify-content-between" >
        <button type="button" disabled={this.state.page<=1}  className="btn btn-dark" onClick={this.handlePreviousClick}>   &larr; Previous</button>
        <button type="button" disabled={this.state.page+1>Math.ceil(this.state.totalresults/this.props.pagesize)}className="btn btn-dark" onClick={this.handleNextClick}>Next &rarr;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

i tried bind method but it does not work for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from `this.page.state` at line 16, it will also be issued by  other links where there is this code.

Try replacing it with `this.state.page`

And please be very careful to not share ApiKey online as you are doing here by asking the question.